# Are structures and classes really equivalent in C++?

Tags: c++, class

Assuming that `struct` is similar to `class` except for the default member privacy, why the following code does not compile?

```
#define class struct
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
     return 0;
}
```

---

**Update**

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:61:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/vector:60,
                 from main.cpp:5:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:86:18: error: ‘struct std::_Sp’ is not a valid type for a template non-type parameter
   template<class _Sp, class _Tp>
                  ^~~
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

Comment: What error dies the compiler give by the way?

Comment: @Matt updated..

Comment: @bobah, I make some `private` members `public` but not the vice versa. How is it inconsistent?

Comment: What you do "should"/"might" work. It's just that you are not doing it consistently (and it's probably impossible doing it with a preprocessor at a scale of the standard library). I did a similar trick `#define private public` with some broken vendor APIs for a single header file and had no probs with it.

Comment: @ar2015 you replace `class` with `struct` where the keyword is not used to declare a type, like in template specifications.

Comment: @ar2015 it's clear from the error message that you've found the issue that `template <class X>` is ok but `template <struct X>` is not. So you are right, they are not completely equivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `class` and a `struct` are equivalent (except for the default privacy)

but grammar doesn't allow `struct` in template:

```
 template <struct S> // Invalid
 /*..*/
```

whereas

```
 template <class C> // valid
 /*..*/
```

or

```
 template <typename T> // valid
 /*..*/
```

Comment: should I pass `struct`s into `<typename T>` or  `<class C>`?

Comment: You might pass `class` or `struct` to template.

Comment: @ar2015 You can even pass non-class type such as `int` into such template.

Comment: @ar2015 `typename` and `class` are equivalent, too (for template parameters)

Answer (score 9):

The behaviour of your code is *undefined*: The C++ standard does not permit the redefinition of keywords.

Perhaps the specific failure is due to `template<class T>` being valid syntax but `template<struct T>` is not? The preprocessor step seems to have ruined the implementation of `<iostream>` on your platform.

(A `class` and `struct` are the same in all respects aside from the default access of member variables and functions - including inheritance, as you point out.

The C++ standard allows you to forward declare as a `struct` and implement as a `class` and vice-versa, although some compilers; older versions of MSVC for example; disallow that.)

Comment: A reference to the wording from the standard would help. One is allowed to do anything in C++ as soon as the level of understanding is sufficient and the readiness to investigate the consequences is there :-)

Comment: Also by default inheritance is different, private for class and public for struct.

Comment: MSVC allows it, but warns.

Comment: As keywords they also have another difference: you can say `template<class T>`, but you can't say `template<struct T>`.

Comment: @MSalters: Which version? IIRC 2015 will fail compilation.

Comment: both VS2017 (in conformance mode) and clang allow it but issue a warning

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is identical when defining members.

However, `class` and `struct` are not synonymous in every context.

`template<class T>` is a synonym for `template <typename T>`. Your `#define` would turn it into `template <struct T>`, which is not allowed. I presume this is why you're getting errors on templates in the standard headers.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers,

To hack into a private visibility scope, the least intrusive way is probably to copy the header to your code base (making sure it goes first in the `-I` path), and make one of your classes a friend of the third party API class that needs hacking. This would be my tool to temporarily patching a suboptimal third party API for production usage.

Another, a more "cowboy" way is to `#define private public` for some limited scope. This one I would not do in a production code base, probably.